# Why is $ required around \oplus in a math environment?

Tags: tables, math-mode, equations

I wrote the following:

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
P & Q & P \oplus Q \\
\hline
\text{T} & \text{T} & \text{F} \\
\text{T} & \text{F} & \text{T} \\
\text{F} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\
\text{F} & \text{F} & \text{F} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{equation*}
```

and the latex compiler complained 'missing $ inserted' on the first line of the table (the one with the \oplus code. I changed that line to:

```
P & Q & P $\oplus$ Q \\
```

and it worked. If equation is a math environment, why is LaTeX requiring \oplus to be enclosed between $ symbols?

Comment: `array` instead of `tabular`.

Comment: `tabular` is a text environment (you don't need those `\text` conmmands, but better as the first comment says is to use `array` instead of `tabular` then each cell is in math (that is the only difference)

Comment: I see. I didn't know that tabular would put me back in text mode. I changed it to an array and kept the texts around the Ts and Fs.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am not sure if `array` is better here, seing that almost all the contents will be typeset as text, not as math; just 3 out of 15 entries will be math; I think, in this case, `tabular` makes the job shorter.  `\begin{equation*}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
$P$ & $Q$ & $P \oplus Q$ \\
\hline
T & T & F \\
T & F & T \\
F & T & T \\
F & F & F \\
\end{tabular}
\end{equation*}` is shorter that its counterpart with `array`.

Comment: If you need many equations in a table, using `>{\(}` and `<{\)}` in the column format might make entries simpler/readable.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I wondered about that, but if it's not really math then `center` might be a better environment than `equation to hold it.

Comment: @Manuel do you want to make an answer?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Agreed; I just noticed the starred version of `equation`, so no numbering is needed, in which case `center` and `tabular` seem better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is already said in the comments. `tabular` puts every cell in text mode, and `array` does the same, but in math mode.

So, in your case,

```
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{c|c|c}
    P & Q & P \oplus Q \\
    \hline
    \text{T} & \text{T} & \text{F} \\
    \text{T} & \text{F} & \text{T} \\
    \text{F} & \text{T} & \text{T} \\
    \text{F} & \text{F} & \text{F} \\
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}
```

By the way, as @GonzaloMedina already said, there is much more text than math in there. Then, may be, you could write

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
    $P$ & $Q$ & $P \oplus Q$ \\
    \hline
    T & T & F \\
    T & F & T \\
    F & T & T \\
    F & F & F \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

EXTRA: IMO you could delete the last `\\`, since there is no rule after the last row.